# Evaluate $\int_0^1\frac{x^a-x^{-a}}{x-1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have heard that:
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^a-x^{-a}}{x-1}dx=\frac1 a-\pi\cot(\pi a)$$
when $-1<a<1$. How would I prove this?

That doesn't have an elementary *indefinite integral*, but the definite integral is quite simple.

Someone suggested I use complex analysis to prove it, but I am relatively new to the subject. (I have gotten up to contour integrals, but I'm not sure how to use them to evaluate this particular integral.) I also tried expanding it with a series, but it didn't help.

Comment: Do you know the digamma function $\psi$?

Comment: I know it's definition and it's recurrence relation. How would it help here?

Comment: It has an anti derivative in terms of the hypergeometric function   ${}_2 F_1$

Comment: Idea: Let $\frac{p}{q}=a$ for some $p,q$ integers. Then, there should be some substitution that turns our integral into a rational function. It might be easier from there. (This only works when $a$ is rational, but the irrationals should follow from continuity or some such.)

Answer (score 14):

> I also tried expanding it with a series, but it didn't help.

It should have helped. If we write

$$\frac{x^{-a}-x^a}{1-x} = (x^{-a}-x^a)\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n,$$

by the monotone convergence theorem, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{x^{-a}-x^a}{1-x}\,dx
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1 (x^{-a}-x^a)x^n\,dx\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n+1-a} - \frac{1}{n+1+a}\right)\\
&= - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{a-n}+\frac{1}{a+n}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{a} - \pi \cot (\pi a)
\end{align}$$

by the well-known partial fraction decomposition of the cotangent.

Comment: That partial fraction decomposition is new to me. I'll add it to my "mathematical toolbox," and i'll see if I can find a simple proof online.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/876758/83702) could be fleshed out into a simple proof. All you need (for real arguments) is that $\pi\cot (\pi x) - \frac{1}{x}$ can be continuously extended to $0$ by the value $0$, that the series is periodic with period $1$, and that both, the cotangent and the series satisfy the functional equation.

Answer (score 5):

It could be a way to use the digamma function $\psi$ which verify 
$$ \psi(a+1)=-\gamma+\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^a}{1-x} \mathrm{d}x, \quad |a|<1,$$
since $$\psi(a)-\psi(1-a)=-\pi \cot (\pi a),$$
$$\psi(1+a)-\psi(a)=\frac{1}{a}.$$

But this is not elementary.

I doubt that you have to prove all from the beginning.

Comment: @user166353 The gamma function's reflection formula $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$ induces a similar formula relating $\psi(z)$ and $\psi(1-z)$.

Comment: Can you prove the reflection formula you have there?

Comment: @user166353 It depends on what you admit. If you know that $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=...$ you take logarithms and differentiate.

Comment: I don't know the proof for that either. (Well, I know the one with the Weierstrass product, but how to prove that that is equivalent to the Gamma function?) I doubt that this is the only way to show this; there must be a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Denote the integral by $ I $. Since $$ x^a-x^{-a}=e^{a\ln(x)}-e^{-a\ln(x)}=2\sinh(a\ln x) .$$

Substituting $\ln x= u $, we get
$$ I=\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{ 2\sinh au}{e^u-1  }e^udu $$

To change the limits of the integral to more convenient one, again substitue $ u=-t$ we have 
\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac {2\sinh at}{e^{-t }-1} e^{-t} dt
\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2\sinh at}{e^{t/2}(e^{-t/2}-e^{t/2})}dt
\\
&=\int_0^{ \infty }e^{-t/2}\frac {\sinh at}{\sinh (t/2)} dz
\end{align}
Now consider the function $$ f (z)=\frac{e^{(a-\frac{1}{2})z}}{\sinh (z/2)} $$ and integrate over the closed rectangle $C: \pm R, i R$. Don't forget to jump by a small contours on $0, i\pi $.  Clearly, $ f (z) $ is analytic on and inside the contour $ C $. Hence by Cauchy Goursat Thm.  $\int_{c } f (z) dz=0$. . .